# Why is a grid element is seen through in the grid through a flexbox element?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 95%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 21.26% 78.64%;
  column-gap: 6px;
  row-gap: 5px;

}

.one, .two, .three,
.four, .five, .six{
  background-color: #abcdef;
}

.one img, .two img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.four {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 35px;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.six {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

nav {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Flex Container */
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

/* Responsive Nav Bar */
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav ul {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    nav ul li {
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    <img src="./assets/img/top-left-background-new.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <img src="./assets/img/top-right-background-new.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
  </div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRQE4.jpg

They're all grid elements and the navigation menu is flexbox. So the underlying grid element 6 is seen through the dropdown i.e. when flex direction changes to column. There is no z-index in the code but it works as expected if I set element 6 z-index to a negative number.

Comment: Because you have a set height on the menu holding the div so it overflows.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you very much! Why not answer and I will accept